# BASH : merge two directories and delete duplicated data

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i want to compare the content of two folders and delete duplicated data, actually i wrote a script (BASH) but i think it's not the right way to do it (i use loops to iterate over directories content and a lot of diff commands , that make it too much time consuming).

I'll explain the context :

I have two directories :

1-

```
  dir1/ 
       Student1/
                homework1 
                homework2 

       Student2/
                homework1
                homework2
```

2-

```
  dir2/ 
       Student1/
                homework1
                homework2 

       Student3/
                homework1
                homework2
```

suppose that student1/homework1 folder contains the same data in dir1 and dir2, unlike homework2 which contains different data

the output directory should contains :

```
       Student1
              homework1                 //same name , same content ==> keep one homework
              homework2
              homework2_dir2                //same name different content ==> _dir2

       Student2
              homework1 
              homework2 

       Student3
              homework1
              homework2
```

What do you think the optimal way in term of time and reliability (filenames problem, etc..) to do such kind of operation ?

Thank you ;)

PS: dir* and Student* and homework* are **directories**

PS2: PLEASE i am not looking to this model of answer :

```
loop over student 
  loop over student homeworks
      test on homework existance
      diff on homework content
        if diff copy
  end
```

end

if i have alot of student and alot of homeworks with only one difference (only one homework that differ), the script take alot of time with the above solution

Comment: Write a bash script to build a `git` repo. let `git` manage the history.

Comment: @kev i cannot install git on the machine, i have to use bash basic command, but i am interested to know how i can do that with git, can you please explain more ???

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that dir1 and dir2 are relative paths with no directories (i.e. no slashes in dir1 or dir2):

```
dir1=dir1
dir2=dir2
cd $dir1
BASEDIR=$(pwd)
for studentdir in *
cd $BASEDIR/$studentdir
do
  for homeworkdir in *
  cd $BASEDIR/$studentdir/$homeworkdir
  do
    for workfile in *
    do
      if cmp $workfile ${CMPDIR}/${studentdir}/${homeworkdir}/${workfile} 2>&1 >/dev/null
      then
        altdir=../${studentdir}_${dir2}
        mkdir ../${altdir}
        ln ${CMPDIR}/${studentdir}/${homeworkdir}/${workfile} ${altdir}
      fi
    done
  done
done
```

I haven't tried this - there may be some typos.

In dir1, recurse into each student folder, and in each student folder into each homework directory.

In each homework directory, use `cmp` on each file to check whether it is byte identical with the matching file in the dir2 subtree.

If different, create an alternate homework directory in the student directory, and link (`ln`) the different file in to the alternate directory.

`cmp` is faster than `diff`; `ln` is faster than `cp`.

That's all, folks.

Comment: Thank you JezC, cmp is for files (homework is a directory and contains alot alot of files), +1 for ln :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's faster than your solution, as you didn't post it.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir output
cp -r dir1/* output

cd dir2
for student in Student* ; do
    (
        cd $student
        out_path=../../output/$student
        [[ -d $out_path ]] || mkdir $out_path
        for file in * ; do
            if [[ -f $out_path/$file ]] ; then
                diff -q $file $out_path/$file \
                    || cp $file $out_path/$file'_dir2'
            else
                cp $file $out_path/$student
            fi
        done
    )
done
```

Comment: and it's pretty much the same as mine, (it's time consuming when i have alot of student and alot of homeworks)

Comment: @bachN: Try adding a `&` after the `)`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to merge all files in two different directories into a new directory and you don't want duplicate files or folders.

Let's say you want to merge them into 'merged' directory.

You can do this:

```
rsync -hrv /dir1 /merged/
rsync -hrv /dir2 /merged/
```

All files in the /dir1 folder will be copied into /merged folder, then the same process will work for /dir2 folder.